# Can't use Amazing Slider

Tags: javascript

I'm on an updated Drupal 7 core site with PHP filters enabled. I have tried all possible best to embed Amazing Slider on Drupal using this code without any luck:

```
<?php echo amazingslider1_output(); ?>
```

On the [amazing slider](https://amazingslider.com/how-to-insert-jquery-slider-to-drupal/)  website, they say to input code to theme file.

I don't know the exact file. I tried **template.php** and **.info** with all the **tpl.php** files. I also tried using same code on article, page, and block but still not working.

Comment: I would suggest you to try other slider modules available in drupal. For example, Flext slider ( https://www.drupal.org/project/flexslider )

If you still go with Amazling Slider let me know.

Comment: Did you do step 1 and 2?